# How to implement the multiselect using JQuery in asp.net mvc?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Need to pass through the form of several categories, as an example here:

[image]

I tried to do as shown in here: *[Using the DropDownList Helper with ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc)*

Test project which they download on Offer for example deleted, if you do a 0, then a washing and surface described, half of the code does not show ...

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery plug in called chosen. You may get it from [here](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).